# Catch required validation form validation - Angular 2

Tags: angular

I would like to ask on how to access the required error in angular 2 so that I can display a specific message for the error.

```
<input type="text" formControlName="username" class="form-control" />
                <p *ngIf="loginForm.controls.username.errors">Email Address required.</p>
                <p *ngIf="loginForm.controls.username.incorrectMailFormat">Email format is invalid.</p>
```

Currently the "loginForm.controls.username.errors" is a general error where in any condition will fall on the elements.

Answer (score 0):

use your code like this

```
<input type="text" formControlName="username" class="form-control" />
   <p *ngIf="loginForm.controls.username.hasError('required')">Email Address required.</p>
   <p *ngIf="loginForm.controls.username.hasError('pattern')">Email format is invalid.</p>
```

By using this code you can specify which error will and according to that you can display exact message.